# How can I stop loud rushing water sounds when we flush?

Tags: water

Whenever we flush or turn on the two outdoor faucets, the sound of rushing water in the pipes is unbearable. If we open any other faucet in the house the sound of rushing water is normal, but flush any of our three toilets or outdoor faucets and the sound will wake you from your sleep. What could this be. I doubt the problem lies with the toilet because it occurs in all three. It is to the point that we hesitate to flush at night in fear of waking up the entire house. I believe I have one of those restrictor valves in the hallway closet. Could that need adjustment?

Comment: How willing are you to open your walls?

Comment: Water flow rate in a pipe solidly attached to the house framing which gives extremely good acoustic coupling. Soft mounting water pipes to insulate depends on if it's a specific spot or whole house. As to the restrictor valve, do you have normal water pressure?

Answer (score -1):

Find the water lines and put some insulation around them. That's about the only thing you can do without running a different kind of line.